# Placing an unknown width element on the right of a centered element without moving it

Tags: html, css, centering

I have a text element centered with `text-align: center;`, I want to place another element (a small inline `<span>`) to the right of it without affecting its position.

Neither of the elements (and especially the `span`) have a known size, so I can't use an offsetting margin on the left of the text element. Is there a way to do that in pure CSS?

Obligatory code that doesn't work:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <h3 id="centered-text">My centered text</h3>
    <span class="to-the-right" style="background-color: blue;">BADGE</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[how's this?](http://jsfiddle.net/p01rddx5/)

```css
#centered-text {
    display: inline-block;
}
#to-the-right {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <div id="centered-text">My centered text</div>
    <div id="to-the-right" style="background-color: blue;">BADGE</div>
</div>
```

I made your H3 not an H3 because it made the BADGE appear weirdly high above the title, but that could be easily corrected by giving the BADGE an attribute like "top: 10px;"

Comment: So much simpler than mine. Thumbs up!

Comment: Thanks! And thanks for fixing my code snippet to run in StackOverflow; I'd been meaning to figure out how to do that but never did :P

Comment: Two buttons to the right compared to the 'normal' code button, and you've got yourself a simple jsFiddle-like editor.

Comment: @RachelGallen He wanted a badge positioned relative to another static element, and that's exactly what absolute positioning does. What's the issue?

Comment: @oxguy3 all i'm saying is if you left it out it would work just as well. it's bad practice

Comment: @RachelGallen If it weren't absolutely positioned, then the #centered-text element wouldn't be centered; it would be pushed slightly off-center by the badge. They specifically asked for the title to be centered and the badge to just hang off it (without affecting how centered it is), so you have to absolutely position it.

Comment: @RachelGallen Here's the different between absolute positioning and not. The centering gets messed up if you don't absolutely position: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gh6L1rza/)

Comment: @oxguy3 and here's the correct way to do it  
jsfiddle.net/yfxcpo1d

Comment: Thanks @oxguy3, this is exactly what I needed in a simple and compact way. While it uses absolute positioning, which can sometimes be tricky, it works.

Comment: @RachelGallen Here's your solution and mine in the same jsfiddle: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/gh6L1rza/1/). Yours is off-center because you need absolute positioning to make this center correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If you can put the `h3` and the `span` inside a wrapper, you can center that wrapper, and position the span outside the wrapper using absolute positioning.

This may be a bit tricky if the h3 is full page width (the span will be outside of the visible area), or if the span contains a longer text (it may wrap awkwardly). However, it's a start, and those issues may not be issues to you.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
h3 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align: center;">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h3 id="centered-text">My centered text</h3>
    <span class="to-the-right" style="background-color: blue;">BADGE</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: While your solution works, I think it's best to avoid the use of wrapper classes if possible. Thanks for contributing :)

Answer (score 0):

Your css is off. Give your div an id and then

```
#divid {margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; width:100%;}
h3 {text-align:center;}
```

Comment: This is not the effect I was trying to achieve. By centering the whole `#myspan`, the badge itself contributes to the centering, so the text is off to the left.

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this without using positioning is to use `display: flex` and a pseudo element.  I personally think that [oxguy3's way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31549811/2591007) is better, but if you want to stay away from positioning then this will also do the trick.

```css
 span {
   background: blue;
 }
 
 div {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
 }
 
 div:before, span {
   content: "";
   flex: 1 1;
 }
 
 * {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>My Centered Text</h3>
  <span>BADGE</span>
</div>
```

This does have a few issues that may or may not matter based on your needs.  If any other elements are needed in the div, then some reconfiguration is necessary, because any new elements also become flex-items and mess with the centering of the `h3`.

Also, as you may notice the span now extends to the edge of the div.  If this is not a problem, then the markup is fine as is, but if it is a problem then wrapping it in another element also fixes this problem, like so:

```css
span {
  background: blue;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}

.container:before,
.badge {
  content: "";
  flex: 1 1;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h3>My Centered Text</h3>
  <div class="badge"><span>BADGE</span></div>
</div>
```

It's not perfect and, as I said, I like [oxguy3's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31549811/2591007) better, but if you want to stay away from positioning, then I think this is a good alternative.

Here's a [codepen with both examples](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqLava?editors=110).

Comment: Great solution to avoid absolute positioning! I'm also fond of flexboxes, but I prefer to avoid the usage of wrapper elements if possible.